# How can I access the rows in a certain column of a DataTable?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

I need to populate the rows in specific columns of a `DataTable`. I have the following setup:

```
Dim Dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
Dim Da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
Dt.Columns.Add("Column 0")
Dt.Columns.Add("Column 1")
Try
        SQLConn.ConOpen()
        Da.SelectCommand = SQLcmd_locCodes
        Da.Fill(Dt)
        SQLConn.ConClose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        SQLConn.ConClose()
    End Try
```

The SqlDataAdapter is filling the table with data from a database. I need to be able to store the data from the database into specific columns in the DataTable. This is what I'm trying (I'm populating a barchart with the data, but you can ignore that part):

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Dt.Rows().Count - 1
        chart.Series("Series1").Points.AddY(Dt.Rows(i)("Column 0").ToString())
        chart.Series("Series1").Points(i).AxisLabel = Dt.Rows(i)("Column 0").ToString()        
Next
```

I know that I'm probably doing some simple task incorrectly. Am I going about accessing the particular rows incorrectly? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The question isn't clear. What exactly doesn't work as desired?

Comment: is there a SQL query somewhere?

Comment: you can use .Where( with your condition!

Comment: Yes, there is a SQL query in the code prior to this. My apologies. There is one of two things going on: (1)The data that I'm getting from the database does not seem to be getting into the DataTable, or (2)I'm going about accessing the DataTable columns incorrectly. I know it isn't a database issue; I've ruled that out.

Comment: not sure I understand... Are you trying update dat in a particular row and column of your datatable? Or are you trying to load specific data from database into the datatable?

Comment: @ElenaDBA I'm trying to load the data from the database into rows that are in specific columns in the DataTable. I'm not sure how the SqlDataAdapter goes about filling the DataTable, so I named the columns in hopes of finding the order in which the data is added to the DataTable.

Comment: do me a favor and temporarily add a datagridview to your form and right after you fill the dt add `DataGridView1.DataSource=dt` and see if the data is coming in like you expect. I haven't tested this but I'm thinking that your data coming from the adapter is either adding new columns or completely overwritting the columns you specified at the top of your code. Meaning the column names you're using are incorrect. (i'll run a test to see if what I'm thinking is correct) EDIT: A quick test showed that the dataadapter appended columns so I'm betting that is what you're running into)

Comment: @CharlesMay Make your comment the answer. I don't know why I didn't realize that, but you are exactly right. Thank you. All I had to do was delete the columns that I made and use `Dt.Rows(i)(0).ToString()`

Comment: Are you having any problems with your current code? If 'Column 0" and "Column 1" are your column names in the database, this should work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the rows in the DataTable like this:

```
For Each dr As DataRow in Dt.Rows
    chart.Series("Series1").Points.AddY(dr("Column 0").ToString())
    chart.Series("Series1").Points(i).AxisLabel = dr("Column 0").ToString())
Next
```

However, you are better off removing this:

```
Dt.Columns.Add("Column 0")
Dt.Columns.Add("Column 1")
```

Just let the DataAdapter name the columns per the column names specified in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my Question & answer (Bottom of page) from Yesterday

[Why I am getting System.Data.DataRowView” instead of real values from my Listbox in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638431/why-i-am-getting-system-data-datarowview-instead-of-real-values-from-my-listbox/34656995?noredirect=1#comment57059262_34656995)

This can be used to extract the information from individual row locations of selected columns.